# Not getting images from s3 bucket in codeigniter

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, codeigniter, amazon-s3

I am trying to get images from s3 bucket but it is not working . i have searched a google lot but cant find any solution for this.

Simply what i want is that, i want images from the s3 bucket and view them in html page .

here is how i am doing this. i am using codeigniter for this. these images are private thats why i am doing this.

hope you can help me .

```
if ($info['photo']!='') 
            {
                $awsAccessKey = 'access_key'; //AWS account access key
                $awsSecretKey = 'secret_key'; //AWS account secret key
                $s3           = new S3($awsAccessKey, $awsSecretKey);

                try 
                {
                    $command = $s3->getObject('bajwa-staging', 'IMG20191013221832.jpg');
                    //The period of availability
                    $request = $s3->createPresignedRequest($command, '+20 minutes');

                    //Get the pre-signed URL
                    $signedUrl = (string) $request->getUri();   
                } 
                catch (Exception $e) 
                {
                    echo 'Message: ' .$e->getMessage();
                    exit;
                }   
            }
```

Comment: "not working" is too broad. What exactly is supposed to be and not happening?

Comment: and even more importantly: what IS happening? what errors are you getting, etc?

Comment: I am not getting any error .... but also i am not getting link of image from bucket